# querySelectorAll returns empty NodeList after loading content with insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript, html, selectors-api, insertadjacenthtml

The situation:

- I'm loading content from a database to my HTML site and insert it with `insertAdjacentHTML`.
  The content is also displayed correctly and all the data is here.
- I want to unfold the card when clicking one of the elements inserted before.
- My event listener works just fine with my test HTML content, but not with the inserted ones. The whole thing doesn't work, because the `.querySelectorAll` returns an empty NodeList.

I've tried to place the script, that loads the content in the head and the one, which holds the event listener to the end, but no change. Actually, the content is in the HTML file when watching with Developer Tools.

This is the template:

```
let markup = `
    <figure class="control__msg" id="${snapshot.key}">
      <div class="control__msg--info">
        <h4>${item.name}</h4>
        <h5>${item.time}</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="control__msg--content" id="content_${snapshot.key}">
        <h4>Email: ${item.email}</h4>
        <h4>Tel.: ${item.phone}</h4>
        <h4>Betreff: ${item.subject}</h4>
        <p>
          ${item.message}
        </p>
      </div>
    </figure>`;

    document.getElementById('messages').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
```

And here is the event listener:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  let targets = document.querySelectorAll('.control__msg');

  targets.forEach(curr => {
    curr.addEventListener('click', e => {
      let content = document.getElementById(`content_${curr.id}`);

      if (content.style.display === 'block') {
        content.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        content.style.display = 'block';
        content.style.animation = 'dropIn .8s 0s forwards ease-out';
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` should never return `null`. It should always return a `NodeList`, which then may be empty.

Comment: I changed the title.. sorry

Comment: Most likely your order of execution is wrong. Add the content/markup in `DOMContentLoaded` aswell (before querying it) and you should be fine.

Comment: Or just remove the DOMContentLoaded listener. That seems to work too.

Comment: First of all: Thank you for your help.
I tried both your solutions, but no success...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation with the following js code:

```
window.selectMode = function() {
    // ...
    const atext = document.querySelectorAll('a.atext');
    console.log('selectMode - atext:', atext);
    // ...
}

//  Option 1:
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', selectMode);

//  Option 2:
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {selectMode();});
```

With option 1 the function selectMode is executed but atext is empty. When the function is executed (e.g. onclick event) later atext is filled.

With option 2 the function selectMode is executed returning a filled nodelist atext.

So it seems to depend on the way how addEventListener is used.

Answer (score 0):

There was no content or HTML described in the question so I just invented some.

Here I use a delegated reference to handle clicks inside the `#messages` container and toggle a show/hide via a `hidden` class in the CSS.  Lots of ways this might be done rather than toggle a class for instance a data attribute with value such as I show here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75405196/125981

```js
function insertNewBlock(item, index) {
  //  console.log(item, index);
  const snapshot = snapshots[index];
  let markup = `
    <figure class="control__msg" id="snapshot-${snapshot.key}">
      <div class="control__msg--info">
        <h4>${item.name}</h4>
        <h5>${item.time.toLocaleTimeString()}</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="control__msg--content" id="content_${snapshot.key}">
        <h4>Email: ${item.email}</h4>
        <h4>Tel.: ${item.phone}</h4>
        <h4>Betreff: ${item.subject}</h4>
        <p>
          ${item.message}
        </p>
      </div>
    </figure>`;

  document.getElementById('messages')
    .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
}

const items = [{
  name: "Barney",
  email: "brubble@example.com",
  time: new Date(),
  phone: "123-456-7890",
  subject: "books for everyone",
  message: "We all need books"
}, {
  name: "Wilber",
  email: "wilber@example.com",
  time: new Date(),
  phone: "123-111-1111",
  subject: "books for everyone",
  message: "I need a book also!"
}, {
  name: "Wilma",
  email: "hereweare@example.com",
  time: new Date(),
  phone: "123-111-1111",
  subject: "books for everyone",
  message: "I need a rick book today!"
}];

const snapshots = [{
  key: 0,
  value: "base"
}, {
  key: 1,
  value: "glove"
}, {
  key: 2,
  value: "bat"
}, {
  key: 3,
  value: "ball"
}];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  items.forEach(insertNewBlock);
  const messageContainer = document.querySelector('#messages');
  //these exist but don't need this really since we are delegating from the container, any added will get included.
  //  document.querySelectorAll('.control__msg');
  messageContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const messages = Array.prototype.slice.call(event.target.children);
    //   console.log(event.target); //where I clicked
    //   console.log(event.currentTarget); //the messages container
    const targ = event.target.closest('.control__msg');
    const msgIndex = messages.indexOf(targ)
    const content = targ.querySelector('.control__msg--content');
    //   console.log(content);
    const classes = content.classList;
    classes.toggle("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.content {}

.control__msg {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: solid 1px #00FF00;
  background-color: #00ff0020;
}

.control__msg--content {
  border: solid #FF0000;
  padding: 1em;
  animation: .8s 0s forwards ease-out;
}

.control__msg--content.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="messages"></div>
```