# Toggle show/hide functions between multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

I have a page on my site which has 3 separate 'hidden' divs. Each with it's own 'show/hide' button.

- Currently... each div and button set functions independently.
- Therefore... if all divs are shown (open) at the same time, they stack according to their respective order.

Instead of that, I would rather restrict the function a bit, so that only div can be shown (open) at a time.

Example: If Div 1 is shown, and the user then clicks the Div 2 (or Dive 3) button, Div 1 (or which ever div is open at the time, will close.

I am not sure how to adjust my code to make that all work together. I have tried a few ideas, but they were all duds. So I posted a generic 'independent' version below.

```js
function show_Div_1() {
  var div1 = document.getElementById("Div_1");
  if (div1.style.display === "none") {
    div1.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    div1.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function show_Div_2() {
  var div2 = document.getElementById("Div_2");
  if (div2.style.display === "none") {
    div2.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    div2.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function show_Div_3() {
  var div3 = document.getElementById("Div_3");
  if (div3.style.display === "none") {
    div3.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    div3.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.div {
  width: 270px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="show_Div_1()">Div 1 - Red</button>
<button type="button" onclick="show_Div_2()" style="margin-left: 4px">Div 2 - Blue</button>
<button type="button" onclick="show_Div_3()" style="margin-left: 4px">Div 3 - Green</button>
<div id="Div_1" class="div" style="background-color:red; display: none;"></div>
<div id="Div_2" class="div" style="background-color:blue; display: none;"></div>
<div id="Div_3" class="div" style="background-color:green; display: none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using data attributes for a toggle.  Why? you can use CSS for them and you can use more than just a toggle - multiple "values".

Here in this example I do your "click" but also added a double click on the button for a third value.  Try some clicks and double clicks!

A bit of overkill perhaps but more than just "toggle" for example you could use this to show "states" of things like a stoplight or any number of things.

Use the `grid` display and move them by just adding a data attribute value and double click it to get it to go (using css) to some `grid-area:`, things like that.

```js
const hideValues = {
  hide: "hidden",
  show: "showme",
  double: "dblclick"
};

function dblClickHander(event) {
  const targetSelecor = event.target.dataset.target;
  const target = document.querySelector(targetSelecor);
  const action = target.dataset.hideme == hideValues.double ? hideValues.hide : hideValues.double;
  const toggleTargets = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-target');
  toggleTargets.forEach(el => {
    el.dataset.hideme = hideValues.hide;
  });
  target.dataset.hideme = action;
}

function toggleEventHandler(event) {
  const targetSelecor = event.target.dataset.target;
  const target = document.querySelector(targetSelecor);
  const showHide = target.dataset.hideme == hideValues.hide ? hideValues.show : hideValues.hide;
  const toggleTargets = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-target');
  toggleTargets.forEach(el => {
    el.dataset.hideme = hideValues.hide;
  });
  target.dataset.hideme = showHide;
}

/* set up event handlers on the buttons */
const options = {
  capture: true
};
/* we do this first to prevent the click from happening */
const toggleButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-button');
toggleButtons.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('dblclick', dblClickHander, options);
});
toggleButtons.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', toggleEventHandler, options)
});
```

```css
.toggle-target {
  width: 270px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.toggle-target[data-hideme="hidden"] {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-target[data-hideme="showme"] {
  display: block;
}

.toggle-target[data-hideme="dblclick"] {
  display: block;
  border: solid 2px green;
  padding: 1rem;
  opacity: 0.50;
}

.red-block {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue-block {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green-block {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="toggle-button" data-target=".red-block">Div 1 - Red</button>
<button type="button" class="toggle-button" data-target=".blue-block">Div 2 - Blue</button>
<button type="button" class="toggle-button" data-target=".green-block">Div 3 - Green</button>
<div class="toggle-target red-block" data-hideme="hidden">red</div>
<div class="toggle-target blue-block" data-hideme="hidden">blue</div>
<div class="toggle-target green-block" data-hideme="hidden">green</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in many ways. I think the best approach in your case could be

BUTTONS

```
<button type="button" onclick="show_div('Div_1')">Div 1 - Red</button>

<button type="button" onclick="show_div('Div_2')" style="margin-left: 4px">Div 2 - Blue</button>

<button type="button" onclick="show_div('Div_3')" style="margin-left: 4px">Div 3 - Green</button>
```

SCRIPT

```
function show_div(div_id) {
    var thisDiv = document.querySelector('#'+div_id);
    var thisState = thisDiv.style.display;
    // close all in any cases
    document.querySelectorAll('.div').forEach(function(el) {
        el.style.display = "none";
    });
    // open this div only if it was closed
    if (thisState == "none" ){
        thisDiv.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```