# jquery validation rules for corresponding radio button on checkbox checked

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I have following models

```
public class Course
{
        public int? id { get; set; }
        public string? name { get; set; }
        public string? tooltip { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
        public int? id { get; set; }
        public string? name { get; set; }
        public string? tooltip { get; set; }
}
public class CourseSelected
{
        public int? id { get; set; }
        public string? text { get; set; }
        public string? desc { get; set; }
}
```

and viewmodel

```
public class studentViewModel
{
public IEnumerable<Department> Department { get; set; } = null!; // for dropdown
public IEnumerable<Course> Course { get; set; } = null!; //checkbox
public IEnumerable<CourseSelected> CourseSelected { get; set; } = null!; //checkbox selected


//// some more 
}
```

When student enters his details and select department, he can select courses from these courses list.

[image]

User selected courses need to select either 1 year or 2 years . Radio buttons section will be appeared only if the checkbox is checked. And Radio button is mandatory when submitting the form.

The selected courses should be added to CourseSelected 's id column , and text is 1 year / 2 years.

in the view

```
@foreach (var course in Model. Course)
{
<div>
<label class="float-start ms-md-2 col-md-6">@course.name</label>
<input id="chk_@course.id" type="checkbox" class="col-md-2 mt-1" onclick="showTest(this,@course.id);"/>

</div>

<div id="divCheck_@course.id" style="display:none;" >
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model. CourseSelected[i]. id,new { @id = "hdnqid_"+@course.id })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m. CourseSelected[i].text, "1 year" , new {@name="radio_"+@course.id}) @Html.Label("1 year ", "1 year ")

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m. CourseSelected[i].text, "2 years" , new {@name="radio_"+@course.id}) @Html.Label("2 years ", "2 years ")
</div>

}
```

If I have 100 Courses, in the CourseSelected,without selecting any of course, I have 100 data. How I can add only selected courses to CourseSelected ? And how can I give required field for radio button when only checkbox selected ?

Comment: You could make the radio buttons on runtime when the checkbox is clicked, since your option are pretty static except for the data-type for example course C#

Comment: `Public class Courses` should be `public class Course` perhaps

Comment: radio buttons in a div will be visible when the checkbox is checked. I have a function showTest() to display the div

Comment: Standard naming convention for properties is typically `public string? Name { get; set; }`.  Not sure why they are "nullable" as an empty string would work - and you can have a `Department == null` for the that type.  Note these are NOT part of your question but more observations here.

Comment: Im using dotnet 6. It should be  Department == null.

Comment: This `@foreach (var course in Model. Courses)` is not correct since you have `Courses` as singular not a list hence my comment and you should probably have `List<Course> courses`

Comment: I think you have seen only the model. Not viewmodel. I have  public IEnumerable<Courses> Courses { get; set; } = null!; in viewmodel

Comment: what mark is referring to is that a class' name should be named like its a singular thing (course), an enumeration of `Course` will be named `courses`

Comment: As for the jQuery part (or pure JavaScript) that would work against the rendered HTML and you probably want to toggle the visibility when the `checked` property is true there.  For these I often use a dataset value and then have CSS tagged to that for a 'toggle" although many toggle a class and I have done that in the past (but not as much more recently.  Here is a recent post where I show an example of that https://stackoverflow.com/a/75405196/125981

Comment: Okay. I will check visibilities of div. and will be taking care of class name as well